# How to visualize a $120^\circ$ (or $240^\circ$) rotation of a cube about its body diagonal?

Tags: geometry, visualization

I'm finding [rotational symmetries of a cube](http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/~zabrocki/math4160w03/cubesyms/) and have some difficulties with visualizing $120^\circ$ or $240^\circ$ rotations.

[image]

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried picking up a physical cube and spinning it in your hand?  For example, with a standard six-sided die, holding opposing corners with the $1$ in the top left, $3$ in the top right, and $2$ in the bottom, after $120^\circ$ spin to the right, I now see a $5$ in the top left, a $1$ in the top right, and a $4$ in the bottom.

Comment: @JMoravitz So how do you measure a $60^°$ rotation with a physical cube?

Comment: Assuming the same axis of rotation, instead of it appearing two faces on top and one face at the bottom, it appears two faces at the bottom and one face at the top.  Using the same starting point (1 top left, 3 top right, 2 bottom), after a $60^\circ$ rotation, one has $1$ at the top, $4$ in the bottom left, and $2$ in the bottom right.  Note: the two positions do not look the same (apart from numbers) so it is generally not considered one of the symmetries of the cube.

Comment: Type $x+y$ in google search engine. You will be presented with a function plot in 3-d. Click on the diagram and hold the mouse to rotate the function any way you like.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Do you see the cube in this figure?

Hint:

Projecting the cube on a plane orthogonal to the main diagonal $1-8$ you find a regular hexagon (you can see an explict construction at: [Construct orthogonal projection for plane (matrix form)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725986/construct-orthogonal-projection-for-plane-matrix-form/1727441#1727441)), and you can easily see the angles.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to your sketch, figure out a plane orthogonal to the axis $1-8$, which is a plane $x+y+z=s$.
Start with $s=0$, it will contain only point $8$.
The plane $s=1$, will contain points $3,5,7$ clearly they are symmetric to the axis, so will be at $120°$ over that plane.
Then plane $s=2$ with points$2,4,6$, also at $120°$ among them, but phased $60°$ with respect to previous triple.
And finally $s=3$ with point $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The $90^\circ$ rotation with the cube in its standard orientation is nice to picture:

[image]

Maybe there is something, psychologically, that's nice about vertical rotation axes?

[image]

But as Jmoravitz [suggests](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736129/how-to-visualize-a-120-circ-or-240-circ-rotation-of-a-cube-about-its-bod/1736348#comment3543178_1736129), there is truly no substitute for holding a cube and rotating. Magnus Wenninger's book, [Polyhedron Models for the Classroom](http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED116939.pdf) is a great resource for starting with nice, paper models.